# Cassandra: Table design with timestamp and large dataset

Tags: database-design, cassandra, timestamp, cql

I am having issues querying large volumes of data by a single day. I am looking for advice on creating an efficient table schema.

Table: eventlog

Columns:
recordid (UUID), insertedtimestamp (timestamp), source (Text), event (Text)

If I simply do:

```
CREATE TABLE eventlog (
    recordid uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    insertedtimestamp timestamp,
    source text,
    event text
);
```

Then the below query will get overwhelmed by the volume of data, assuming today is 1/25.

```
select * from eventlog where insertedtimestamp > '2017-01-25';
```

The goal is to select all the records from a single day, knowing we need to be efficient in partitioning using tables with possibly millions of records. How would I design an efficient table schema (What partition key setup)? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you want to get all the record in a single day, you can use this schema

```
CREATE TABLE eventlog (
    day int,
    month int,
    year int,
    recordid uuid,
    insertedtimestamp timestamp,
    source text,
    event text,
    PRIMARY KEY((day,month,year),recordid)
);
```

So all of the data in a single day, will be in a single node. Now you can get data of a date say 2017-01-25 more efficiently with the below query

```
SELECT* FROM eventlog WHERE day = 25 and month = 1 and year = 2017
```

Comment: Hello, is separating the date this way more efficient then just a date without a timestamp? Essentially, 
WHERE day = 25 and month = 1 and year = 2017 
vs.
WHERE date = '2017-01-25' (date is a new timestamp that just stores date, no time)

Comment: you can also use a single field of date type, that contains only date instead of three field

Comment: I am using a single field of date type, containing only the date. Your solution still stands as correct