# Cassandra Schema for retrieving date-ordered records

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

Folks,
  I would like to solve the following with one table in Cassandra.  Said service tracks when users open an asset.  On subsequent events to the same asset, we simply over-write the accessDate.

example record:

> { userId: "string", assetId: "string", accessDate: unixTimestamp }

With this said, we need to fulfill the following access requirements (each requirement has its own bulletpoint for readability):

- Be able to return all assets a user has opened, and at what time.

This is easy to achieve, table could look like:

```
CREATE TABLE user_assets_tracker (
   userId uuid,
   accessDate timestamp,
   assetId uuid,
   PRIMARY KEY (userid, accessDate, assetId)
);
```

This allows us to query for all assets, and when each was last accessed.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_assets_tracker
WHERE userId = 522b1fe2-2e36-4cef-a667-cd4237d08b89
ORDER BY accessDate DESC;
>
```

Dandy.  Now the harder bits, which I am unsure about, was hoping you folks could chime in:

- Show me all the assets user added in the past 30 days.

Naturally the LIMIT here is not what we need. Also, we may need to have 2 tables to achieve this.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_assets_tracker
WHERE userid = 522b1fe2-2e36-4cef-a667-cd4237d08b89
ORDER BY accessDate DESC;
LIMIT 10; ?????
```

- Show me the last accessed item for the user. I think this one is easier, the LIMIT 1 solves that.

This is probably straight forward, with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user_assets_tracker (
   userId uuid,
   accessDate timestamp,
   assetId uuid,
   PRIMARY KEY (userid, accessDate, assetId)
);

SELECT *
FROM user_assets_tracker
WHERE userid = 522b1fe2-2e36-4cef-a667-cd4237d08b89
ORDER BY accessDate DESC;
LIMIT 1;
```

- Retrieve the full record for a particular userId + assetId

Since accessDate comes before assetId in our schema, I am not sure how to do this as well.  Another table?

Thanks!!

PS It seems that [SASI Index](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html) could be the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you are always selecting assetid orderby accessDate desc.
Define your schema with order by accessDate desc

```
CREATE TABLE user_assets_tracker (
    userid uuid,
    accessdate timestamp,
    assetid uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, accessdate, assetid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (accessdate DESC, assetid ASC);
```

Now you don't need to specify order by accessDate desc every time. it will by default order your data by accessDate desc

- Show me all the assets user added in the past 30 days.

First get timestamp of 30 day ago.
Let's current timestamp of 30 day ago is  : `2017-02-05 12:00:00+0000`
Now you can query :

```
SELECT * FROM user_assets_tracker WHERE userid = 522b1fe2-2e36-4cef-a667-cd4237d08b89 AND accessdate >= '2017-02-05 12:00:00+0000'
```

- Retrieve the full record for a particular userId + assetId

If you are using Cassandra 3.0 or above you can use [Materialized Views](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views)
CREATE a Materialized  View :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW user_assets AS
    SELECT *
    FROM user_assets_tracker
    WHERE userid IS NOT NULL AND assetid IS NOT NULL AND accessdate IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, assetid, accessdate);
```

Now if you want to get all data with userid and assetid, here is the query

```
SELECT * FROM user_assets WHERE userid = 522b1fe2-2e36-4cef-a667-cd4237d08b89 AND assetid = 1d45e6c2-02a1-11e7-aac5-b9ab92bee74c;
```

Here is another thing, if huge data is inserted into a single user, you should add time bucket with userid as partition key.For more check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857183/2320144

Comment: GREAT THANK YOU!  Quick question, I see that in the first example you have (userid, accessdate, assetid) , but in the second you have (userid, assetid, accessdate);

How will the single query work then?